# Как открыть доступ к порту в Debian?

Tags: linux, debian

Есть следующий вывод netstat в Debian 9:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это снимок из виртуальной машины, между ней и хостом настроено взаимодействие. Машина имеет адрес 192.168.56.102. И по адресу ***192.168.56.102:8280/некий_нужный_путь*** всё работает. Однако, командой ***telnet 192.168.56.102 9443*** не удаётся подключиться. В чём проблема? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была с файерволлом. Он блокировал доступ.